# Bootstrap column won't fill remaining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My content is only a few lines long but I want the page to carry on for the remaining height.

```
<div style="background: #e0e0e0;">
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background: #f9f9f9;">
      <div class="col mb-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 mt-5">{{object.name}}</h1>


        <p>City: New York</p>

        <div class="row mt-5">

          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Show</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for show in shows %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2019</th>
                <td>Test Title</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add this CSS and try `.container>.row{min-height:100%;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try To Specify in The Css min-height: 100vh for the `<main>` tag and the  `<div style="background: #e0e0e0;"></div>` Tag

Answer (score 0):

use min-height and max-height

```css
.row{
min-height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="background: #e0e0e0;">
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background: #f9f9f9;">
      <div class="col mb-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 mt-5">{{object.name}}</h1>


        <p>City: New York</p>



        <div class="row mt-5">

          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Show</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for show in shows %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2019</th>
                <td>Test Title</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked - but doesnt go all the way to the end of the page. Only 3/4 of the way

Comment: just play with the height it should work in range of 700 approx. Don't forget to vote